# Aliases outside web root inside .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

> **TL;DR:** Is there any way to have a domain's sub-directory `http://company.com/subdir` point to a directory outside the web root using only `.htaccess` with no access to the server's configuration?

I have a web site `company.com` that runs three country-specific copies of a CMS on a shared hosting package (Apache 2, PHP 5).

The CMS is split into two directories:

```
/app      <----- Non-public content, to be placed outside the web root
/htdocs   <----- Public content
```

I would like to have each of the three country-specific CMSes as sub-directories to the main domain:

```
www.company.com/de/  <-- 1st copy
www.company.com/ch/  <-- 2nd copy
www.company.com/at/  <-- 3rd copy
```

the obvious problem with this structure, each CMS's `/app` directory would need to be put into a separate location outside the web root. However, for maintenance reasons (I am passing on my projects to another company) I would like to prevent this.

The ideal solution for me would be that each copy of the CMS resides in a directory outside the web root:

```
/htdocs <------- public web root

/de/app
/de/htdocs
/ch/app
/ch/htdocs
/at/app
/at/htdocs
```

thus ensuring that the `app` directory can't be accessed from outside.

Each CMS's public `htdocs` directory would be made available to the world selectively using an `Alias` directive:

```
Alias /de ../de/htdocs
Alias /ch ../ch/htdocs
Alias /at ../at/htdocs
```

But this is not possible from within `.htaccess` (I get a 500 error) where `Alias` directives are  not possible to specify, and as far as I know, `mod_rewrite` directives can only specify targets inside the web root (correct?)

As far as I can see, what I want to do is **impossible to do** in a shared hosting environment, but I thought I'd check whether anybody here has any ideas, as it would be a *huge* relief for me to be able to do it this way.

I can put a .htaccess into the parent directory (one level above web root), but that doesn't seem to change anything.

I hope it's put clear enough. If it isn't, please let me know and I will clarify.

Switching away from the shared hosting is not an option, neither is asking the hosting company about relaxing the rules - they are *very* good at what they do, but also very strict and conservative about individual customizations.

Leaving each `app` directory in the web root, and blocking access to it using `Deny from all` or similar, is not an option either.

Answer (score 2):

The "Alias" directive is not allowed in .htaccess files.  According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias, "Alias" is only allowed in "server config, virtual host".  That's why you get a 500 error when you set it in the .htaccess context.

It's helpful to review the context flag in the apache manual when you have a server error, if you're unsure of the context proper for your directive.

I think you might easily accomplish this with some symlinks, if your host allows FollowSymlinks:

```
/htdocs/de -> /de/htdocs
/htdocs/ch -> /ch/htdocs
/htdocs/at -> /at/htdocs
```

Comment: Argh, hadn't thought about symlinks at all. I'll try that.

Comment: Too bad - no dice. I can create symlinks, but Apache will give me a 403 even though I have activated `Options +FollowSymlinks`. That must mean that either FollowSymlinks is globally deactivated, or there is some other reason why this doesn't work. Was a good shot though, +1 and thanks for reminding me that `Alias` doesn't work *at all* from within .htaccess

Comment: If it's shared hosting, then this makes sense.  They might have set SymLinksIfOwnerMatch, though -- are the links and destinations owned by the same user?  If your host doesn't have that set -- you might ask if they would set it for you.

Comment: I have only one FTP account created in the package and I'm uploading everything with that, so the owner *should* match. I'm suspecting that I'm forbidden from specifying a symlink target outside the web root somehow.

Comment: Might be SeLinux stopping you using symlinks in this way :)